# Write a cell array in text file using Matlab

Tags: matlab, cell

I have a cell array with the size of 1*15.

```
whos C
Name      Size             Bytes  Class    Attributes
C         1x15            222520  cell
```

In each cell, there are 1170 elements. The 15 cells are mixture of strings and numbers. I want to save all these elements to a text file with coma as delimiter.

I tried to use the function [dlmcell](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25387-write-cell-array-to-text-file), dlmcell('file_out.txt.,C,'delimiter',','), it can only write the first value of each cell to the text file. And the cell contains string cannot be write to the text file.

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just found in http://cn.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/write-to-delimited-data-files.html
write cell data using fprintf.
May help!

```
[nrows,ncols] = size(C);
for row = 1:nrows
    fprintf(fileID,formatSpec,C{row,:});
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried but it returns an error as below.                              Error using fprintf
Function is not defined for 'cell' inputs.